# Where is req.variable stored?

Tags: node.js, express, variables, cookies, req

Similar question (but NOT a duplicate): [How do i store request-level variables in node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10983500/how-do-i-store-request-level-variables-in-node-js)

Consider this following code:

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
   req.someVariable = "Hello";
   res.send(req.someVariable + ' world!');
});
```

Where is `req.someVariable` stored? In a cookie? Does this apply for the user only or everyone? Also, what's the difference between these and storing them in sessions/cookies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to `req` being just a javascript object variable, stored in memory, do note express has a `res.locals` object variable that persist through the request/response cycle.

If you want to store any user information, you should be using the `res.locals` object so you do not accidentally overwrite other important objects.

#### res.locals

> An object that contains response local variables scoped to the
> request, and therefore available only to the view(s) rendered during
> that request / response cycle (if any). Otherwise, this property is
> identical to app.locals.
> This property is useful for exposing request-level information such as the request path name, authenticated user, user settings, and
> so on.

http://expressjs.com/en/5x/api.html#res.locals

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.locals.user = req.user
  res.locals.authenticated = !req.user.anonymous
  next()
})
```

Note: `res.locals` on it's own is not sent together with the response (e.g. `res.send`). It's only accessible in your nodejs app.

#### Cookies

Cookies are information bits that you want to send to the client's browser (stored in browser memory). The client can then send the cookie back to your nodejs app. These are different from `req` and `res` properties.

Cookie can store for example, an authentication token, which can be stored in the client's browser, and provided to the nodejs app on every request.

For security, you can use a httpOnly cookie which cannot be modified by browser javascript.

Comment: So where are `req.locals` stored?